# Как сделать блок который будет инверсировать цвет находящийся над ним?

Tags: css, css3, svg, scss

Нужно сделать чтобы элемент, который будет добавляться как псевдоэлемент (в данном случае картинка) мог инверсировать цвет текста относительно своего расположения как показано на скриншоте:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: filter: invert(1);

Answer (score 1):

Это можно решить вот таким методом:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background: url("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg") 80% 50% no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit." 
           "Delectus similique optio maxime corrupti illum veniam harum dolor quidem eius."
           "Deleniti.";
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(1000%);
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>Apr 30, 2022 </p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Delectus similique optio maxime corrupti illum veniam harum dolor quidem eius. 
      Deleniti.</h1>
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: буквы в `:after` не всегда накладываются на буквы в `h1`